How to prove the set $\left\{ q\in\mathbb{Q}\ |\ q^{2}\le2\right\}$ has no supremum in $\mathbb{Q}$ without Real numbers?
What I want: A proof that the set $\left\{ q\in\mathbb{Q}\ |\ q^{2}\le2\right\} $ has no least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$.
The constraint: I don't want this proof to assume we know of the existence of $\sqrt{2}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. I want it to work "within" $\mathbb{Q}$ itself.
Without the constraint my proof would go like this: given some $b>0\in\mathbb{Q}$, we know $b^2\ne 2$ since for no rational $b$ we have $b^2=2$. Assume $b^2>2$, so $b>\sqrt{2}$. Now use the fact the rationals are dense to obtain $c\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sqrt{2}<c<b$, showing $b$ is not the least upper bound. If $b^2<2$ then again by denseness we obtain $b<c<\sqrt{2}$ which shows $b$ is not an upper bound.
This proof uses a denseness argument which involves $\sqrt{2}$ itself; I don't think this argument is provable without assuming $\sqrt{2}$ exists.

The function $x \to x^2$ is increasing on $\mathbb{Q}^{>0}$, so this boils down to the classic result that there exists no $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ with $q^2 = 2$.

Assuming you know that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, a topological proof is possible. Let me know if you want me to respond with such an answer; otherwise Anomaly's answer is more than sufficient.

Let $r \in \Bbb{Q}$ be the l.u.b. of the unnamed set.  Necessarily $r^2 \geq 2$, it is an ancient fact that $r^2 = 2$ is impossible, and we are free to assume $r < 3/2$.  Let $d = r^2-2$.  We have $0 < d < 1/4$.  Then, (detail left to reader:) $$  2 < (r-d/6)^2 = r^2 - rd/3 + d^2/36 < r^2  \text{,}  $$ contradicting that $r$ was the l.u.b. in $\Bbb{Q}$.  (This is basically just applying an inefficient variant of the manual square-root algorithm.)
